# using netplan to create a gateway

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gateway, netplan

I am trying to use netplan to set up a gateway.  Here are some details of what I have set up:

1. I'm running 20.04
2. I have 5 NICs (enp5s0, enp4s0f1, enp4s0f0, enp3s0f1, enp3s0f0)
3. The enp4* and enp3* NICs are on a single PCIx card
4. The gateway sits behind my ISP provided router (it is garbage but works most of the time).  The gateway is statically configured to 192.168.0.50 and it connects via enp5s0.  The ISP router is on 192.168.0.1
5. the 4 NICs on the card will service various other upstream laptops/tablets/phones/other switches/desktops and forward everything to my ISP router.  There are ~20 devices upstream from the gateway.
6. The gateway has pihole installed on it.  Pihole is configured (via dnsmasq I believe) to provide IP4 addresses in 192.168.1.1/24
7. netplan is setup with the following (copied from screen because the machine has no internet connectivity.  There might be copy errors):

   ```
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
       enp5s0:
         dhcp4: no
         addresses: <192.168.0.50/24>
         gateway4: 192.168.0.1
       switchports:
         match:
           name: enp<3-4>*
     bridges:
       br0:
         interfaces: <enp5s0, switchports>
         addresses: <192.168.1.1/24>
         dhcp4: true
   ```

   This configuration generates and applies without error.
8. I have setup `iptables` to NAT from enp5s0 and br0 (i`ptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE`).  The `ip_forward=1` kernel parameter has been set.

However,  I am having mixed results:

1. I can connect to 192.168.1.1 pihole interface from the gateway
2. the clients behind the gateway are served IP addresses successfully
3. the clients behind the gateway can access the pihole interface

   but:
4. I can't ping 8.8.8.8 from the gateway, which pretty much sums it up.  Connectivity from the gateway to the internet isn't working so upstream clients can't connect either.

My route tables looks like this:

```
Destination   Gateway       Genmask         Flags   Iface
0.0.0.0       192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0         UG      enp5s0
192.168.0.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U       enp5s0
192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U       br0
```

Any ideas on what I can try to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get it to work with the following setup. I probably don't need to set the routes as much as I do but it does work.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
    enp4s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
    enp4s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
    enp3s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
    enp3s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp4s0f1, enp4s0f0, enp3s0f1, enp3s0f0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
```